# При входе в сессию (логин) пишет, что пароль не првильный. Drupal 7 + uLogin (опционально)

Tags: drupal, пароль, ulogin, хеширование

При входе в сессию (логин) пишет, что пароль не првильный, хотя от 100% правильный.

Войти в акк можно только восстановлением пароля.

---

### ***Более подробно и поэтапно:***

1. Создаю пользователя (логин/пароль) > вход (смотрим хеш, ок)
2. Выход из сессии (хеш не меняется)
3. Вход (логин/пароль) > "Неверный пароль" (смотрю хеш, не поменялся)
4. Восстановление пароля > мейл со ссылкой > новый пароль (смотрим хеш, все ок, поменялся)...
5. Выход > вход ... все то же самое

В общем такое впечатление, что хеш для проверки считается не правильно,
ибо пароль правильный и он не менялся.
**А может проблема вообще не в этом?**
Пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть причина и где рыть?

Дополнительно: использую uLogin, но для проверки его отключал — результат тот же.
Кстати, при логине через соц. сети (где пароль не запрашивается — все ок, вход выполняется без проблем)

Answer (score 1):

Первое что приходит в голову - почистить куки браузера. 
Движок не обновляли? Какая версия движка?
Есть ещё момент, если форма логина кастомная, то проверьте есть ли в форме `<input name="form_id" type="hidden" value="user_login" >`, без передачи этого параметра будет выкидывать аналогичный эксепшн.